# Getting values from a directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have used a `datepicker` directive in my code. My idea is, when a date is selected from the `datepicker`, the selected date must be printed on the screen.

Any suggested code regarding this issue?
This was the code :

```
  <script language="javascript">
     angular
        .module('myapp', ['ngMaterial','ngMessages'])
        .controller('dateController', dateController);

     function dateController ($scope) {
        $scope.myDate = new Date();

        }

      </script>
      </head>

        <body ng-app="myapp"> 
  <div class="datepickerdemo" ng-controller="dateController as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
     <md-content>
        <h4>Standard Date Picker</h4>
        <md-datepicker 
           ng-model="myDate" 
           md-placeholder="Enter Date" ></md-datepicker>
           </md-content>

           </div>
           </body>
           </html>
```

And my doubt is how can get selected date  when it is changed

Comment: please show us what you have done so far

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please tell what have you tried till now and what is the issue you are stuck in? A working js fiddle would really help.

Answer (score 1):

The local `scope` property `&` might be the right thing for that.
You can define a callback function using the chosen date as a parameter.

In your directive JS:

```
return {
    ...
    scope: {
        onSelect: '&'
    }
    ...
}
```

When using your directive you can define an `on-select` parameter giving a callback function, that you can use e.g. inside your `link` function.

Using local `scope` properties is the way to go in AngularJS, when exchanging data between a directive and the outer "world".

More info at [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)